# Perform Same Query For Every Id in List

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table called scores. id is the auto-incremented primary key.

| id | player_id | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 1 | 57 |
| 3 | 2 | 434 |
| 4 | 3 | 11 |
| 5 | 3 | 132 |
| 6 | 4 | 32 |
| 7 | 4 | 100 |
| 8 | 4 | 21 |

Given a list of player ids, I need to return the last score received from each player_id in the list (i.e. the score that has the greatest id with the given player_id).

Using the data above, player 1 should return 57, player 2 should return 434, player 3 should return 132, and player 41 should return 21.

Let's say I am given a list containing player_ids 3 and 4. I want to create a single query that returns  132 for the first row and 21 for the second row.

The individual queries would be

```
select score  from scores where player_id = 3   order by id desc limit 1; 
select score  from scores where player_id = 4   order by id desc limit 1;
```

I'm having trouble combining these two into one query. I want to avoid using UNION because the list could contain hundreds of player_ids.

Comment: Please tag the database product you are using

Comment: Use a windowed function something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group

Comment: Yeah, "groupwise-max" is tricky to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get desired result from multiple approach.

**Approach 1**

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Scores
WHERE id IN (
        SELECT Max(id)
        FROM scores
        GROUP BY player_id
        )
```

In this approach, sub-query `SELECT Max(id) FROM scores GROUP BY player_id` gets the greatest/max `id` for each `player_id`. And gets result on the basis of those id.

**Approach 2**

```sql
SELECT s.player_id
    ,s.id
    ,s.score
FROM scores s
JOIN (
    SELECT player_id
        ,MAX(id) AS max_id
    FROM scores
    GROUP BY player_id
    ) t ON s.player_id = t.player_id
    AND s.id = t.max_id;
```

In this apporoach, sub-query is quite similar to above one but it additionally returns `player_id` also which is used for joining to retrive the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
select t.id, t.player_id, t.score
  from scores t
where not exists (select 1 from scores tt
                  where tt.player_id = t.player_id
                    and tt.id > t.id);
```

Another option is to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function as follows:

```
select t.id, t.player_id, t.score from
  (select t.id, t.player_id, t.score,
         row_number() over (partition by t.player_id order by t.id desc) as rn
    from scores t) t
where rn = 1;
```

**NOTE:** You can add one more condition in `WHERE` clause to include only required `player_id` like `player_id in (3,4)`